# Showing edit button to current_user only (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to allow users to show the edit button only if the profile belongs to them. Currently, they're only allowed to edit the profile if it belongs to them but I can't seem to hide the button. I have this so far

```
<% if request.original_url == request.base_url + "current_user.id" %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(current_user), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>&nbsp;
<% end %>
```

This is what I'm trying to compare:

request.original_url => localhost:3000/users/random_user

request.base_url + "users/" + current_user.id => localhost:3000/users/current_user

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Authorization**

To give you some perspective, you'll be looking for something called [*authorization*](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-authorization.html).

This is different from *authentication* because it deals with *permissions*, rather than identifying *your identity*. I'll get into how this works in a minute.

---

To solve your problem, here's what you need to do:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(current_user), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs", if user_signed_in? && current_user == @user %>
```

I'm guessing you're showing this on a `user#show` action, which can be invoked using the following code:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

This means that if you have the following routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users
```

you'll have access to `@user` and `current_user`. It's important to note that `current_user` != `@user`. Although `weezing`'s answer is succinct, it does not validate whether the user is the one which owns the page *authorized*; just that the user is *authenticated*

---

Thus, you have several specifications:

> 1. You need to know if the user is actually logged in
> 2. You need to make sure your `logged-in` user has the *authorization* to edit the profile (IE is it theirs)

I would highly recommend looking into the use of `gems` such as [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [`Pundit`](https://github.com/elabs/pundit). I'll show you CanCanCan:

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
   include CanCan::Ability

   def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      can :edit, Article, id: user.id
   end
end

#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(@user) if can? :edit, @user %>
```

There is a [great resource here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

Comment: Thanks a lot Rich. Very helpful. Next time I'll use one of the gems you suggested for sure.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to write somthing on your own - especially for learning purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (little bit simpler):

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(current_user), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this is not what the question is asking. This will show the button if a user is logged in. The correct answer is what @RichPeck posted.